# Running a thread which doesn't return back anything in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, discord, python-asyncio

I am writing a bot for Discord which can create a timer and notify when it runs out. With the code that i have right now the bot sleeps for that amount of time and then messages saying that time is up.
(uses discord.py)

```
@bot.command(name='create')
async def create_schedule(ctx, title: str, mins: float):
    await ctx.send(f'Created schedule for {title} in {mins} minutes')
    time.sleep(60*mins)
    await ctx.send(f'{title} is starting now!')
```

But the problem is that i can't create two schedules at the same time since the second one will be put in queue, wait for the first one to finish and then start the timer.
I have tried to create a new thread and sleep in that thread so that i can accept another create command but that didn't work.

```
async def wait(ctx, title, mins):
    time.sleep(int(60*mins))
    await ctx.send(f'{title} is starting now!')

@bot.command(name='create')
async def create_schedule(ctx, title: str, mins: float):
    await ctx.send(f'Created schedule for {title} in {mins} minutes')
    threading.Thread(target=wait, args=(ctx, title, mins)).start()
```

I dont want to wait for the `wait()` function to finish before i accept another command. I just want to start up the timer, set it aside and continue parsing other commands. How can i do this?  BTW The `wait()` function has a way of displaying that the time is up (`ctx.send(f'{title} is starting now!')`) so it doesn't have to return anything or call any other part of the program after the timer is done sleeping (and i don't want it to do anything else after the time is up).
Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't use `time.sleep` - it blocks the asyncio event loop. Use [asyncio.sleep](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.sleep) instead.

Comment: it give me an error saying that `wait()` was never awaited.

Comment: You have to do `await asyncio.sleep(60*mins)`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I kind of figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code made it work. I changed from create a thread to using a Task from asyncio. Also as pointed out by @dano, i used `asyncio.sleep` instead of `time.sleep`

```
async def wait(ctx, title, mins):
    await asyncio.sleep(int(60*mins))
    await ctx.send(f'{title} is starting now!')

@bot.command(name='create')
async def create_schedule(ctx, title: str, mins: float):
    await ctx.send(f'Created schedule for {title} in {mins} minutes')
    asyncio.create_task(wait(ctx, title, mins))
```